# How to pass credentials to PHP api endpoint located on .htaccess protected apache web server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, webserver

I currently have an apache server running and an api endpoint in PHP

`https://myserver.com/api.php`

The server is utilizing .htaccess authentications (auth box pops up when first open URLs).

I can make a post/get request to my endpoint successfully without any authentication, but I wonder if I enable the auth, how do I pass the credentials in a post or get request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using either post or get you can send creds in the URL like so...

```
http://username:password@myserver.com/api.php
```

Comment: BTW, will putting credentials in URL expose/leak them somewhere in transit?

Comment: it definitely can, especially if you're not using SSL. that's why you don't see this used much these days.

Comment: I do have a self signed SSL, it's just a home web server but I don't want any kind of attacks to it, I could use a authentication check within my api.php, but the reason I use apache auth is because I hope fail2ban can do something to protect brute force attack, I'm not an expert so I'm not sure haha

Comment: Is it a publicly facing home server? If not, dont even worry about it. Youre safe.

Comment: Yeah it is, I have a DNS attached to my home IP address on port 443